# Campo vazio nos inputs substituindo valores de campos no BD

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema acadêmico. O código abaixo é para inserção de notas do aluno, o problema está na hora de preencher o 2º, 3º ou 4º bimestre, pois toda vez que for inserir uma nota nova, é preciso repetir a do(s) bimestre(s) anterior(es), pois se não colocar o valor do bimestre passado ele ira salvar o campo vazio no BD.

```
<div class="insercao-notas">
    <form method="post" action="cad-notas.php">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="aluno_id" placeholder="Inisira o código do aluno" required="">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="nome_aluno" placeholder="Insira o nome do aluno" required="">
        <select class="input" name="disciplina">
            <option value="1">Português</option>
            <option value="2">Matemática</option>
            <option value="3">Ciência</option>
            <option value="4">Geografia</option>
            <option value="5">História</option>
            <option value="6">Arte</option>
            <option value="7">Inglês</option>
            <option value="8">Educação física</option>
            <option value="9">Educação e trabalho</option>
            <option value="10">Ensino religioso</option>
        </select>
        <span class="texto">Insira as notas abaixo:</span>
        <input class="bt-enviar" type="submit" name="bt-enviar" value="Enviar notas">
        <br/>
        <label class="texto">Bimestre 1: </label>
        <input class="notas" type="number" name="nota1" size="2" step="0.01">
        <br />
        <label class="texto">Bimestre 2: </label>
        <input class="notas" type="number" name="nota2" size="2" step="0.01">
        <br />
        <label class="texto">Bimestre 3: </label>
        <input class="notas" type="number" name="nota3" size="2" step="0.01">
        <br />
        <label class="texto">Bimestre 4: </label>
        <input class="notas" type="number" name="nota4" size="2" step="0.01">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Parte do php**

```
   <?php
     include_once("../../../php/connect.php");

     session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]) || !isset($_SESSION["name-adm"])) {
    header("Location:../../../index.php");
   }
   ?>
 <?php
   $id = $_POST['aluno_id'];
   $nome = $_POST['nome_aluno'];
   $disciplina = $_POST['disciplina'];
   $nota1 = $_POST['nota1'];
   $nota2 = $_POST['nota2'];
   $nota3 = $_POST['nota3'];
   $nota4 = $_POST['nota4'];
   $enter = $_POST['bt-enviar'];

  if (isset($enter)) {
    $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE aluno_id LIKE '$id' AND nome LIKE '$nome'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 0){
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Por favor, insira o ID  e o nome de alunos cadastrados!!'); window.location.href='notas.php';</script>";
    }else {
        $pesquisa = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM boletim WHERE aluno_id LIKE '$id' AND disc_id LIKE '$disciplina'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($pesquisa) == 1) {
            echo "
                <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('O aluno já possui nota nesta disciplina!');
                    window.location.href='pesquisa-notas.php';
                </script>
            ";
        } else {
            $notas = ("INSERT INTO boletim (disc_id, aluno_id, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4)");
            $notas .= ("VALUES ('$disciplina', '$id', '$nota1', '$nota2', '$nota3', '$nota4')");

            $salvar = mysqli_query($con, $notas);

            $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

            echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Notas inseridas com sucesso!');
                    window.location.href='pesquisa-notas.php';
                </script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo deste gênero, está bem simplório, porém esta facil de entende, você verifica se uma nota esta retornando vazio, e bloqueia

```
 <?php
     include_once("../../../php/connect.php");

     session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]) || !isset($_SESSION["name-adm"])) {
    header("Location:../../../index.php");
   }
   ?>
 <?php
   $id = $_POST['aluno_id'];
   $nome = $_POST['nome_aluno'];
   $disciplina = $_POST['disciplina'];
   $nota1 = $_POST['nota1'];
   $nota2 = $_POST['nota2'];
   $nota3 = $_POST['nota3'];
   $nota4 = $_POST['nota4'];
   $enter = $_POST['bt-enviar'];

  if (isset($enter)){ 
    if($nota1 == '' || $nota2 == '' || $nota3 == '' || $nota4 == ''){
                echo("
                <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Você precisa inserir uma nota válida!');
                    window.location.href='pesquisa-notas.php';
                </script>
                ");
    }
    else{

    $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE aluno_id LIKE '$id' AND nome LIKE '$nome'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 0){
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Por favor, insira o ID  e o nome de alunos cadastrados!!'); window.location.href='notas.php';</script>";
    }else {
        $pesquisa = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM boletim WHERE aluno_id LIKE '$id' AND disc_id LIKE '$disciplina'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($pesquisa) == 1) {
            echo "
                <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('O aluno já possui nota nesta disciplina!');
                    window.location.href='pesquisa-notas.php';
                </script>
            ";
        } else {




                $notas = ("INSERT INTO boletim (disc_id, aluno_id, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4)");
                $notas .= ("VALUES ('$disciplina', '$id', '$nota1', '$nota2', '$nota3', '$nota4')");

                $salvar = mysqli_query($con, $notas);

                $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

                echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Notas inseridas com sucesso!');
                        window.location.href='pesquisa-notas.php';
                    </script>";


        }
    }
    }
}
?>
```